# How to rename and move a serialized object's properties using Newtonsoft contract resolvers

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft to serialize and deserialize objects. Here is a sample of how my data is structured:

```
[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class BaseSerializer
{
    [JsonProperty("players")] public IList<PlayersSerializer>? Players { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class PlayersSerializer
{
    [JsonProperty("player1")] public PlayerSerializer? Player1{ get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("otherProp")] public string? OtherProp { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class PlayerSerializer
{
    [JsonProperty("name")] public string? Name{ get; set; }
}
```

If I pass in this JSON:

```
{
  "players": [
    {
      "player1": {
        "name": "Robert Bobbert"
      },
      "otherProp": "Tasty"
    }
  ]
}
```

To:

```
var test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BaseSerializer>(json);
```

Then define this custom ContractResolver to rename the property:

```
public class MyCustomContractResolver: DefaultContractResolver
{
    public static readonly MyCustomContractResolverInstance = new();

    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Dictionary<string, string>> _propertyNameConverter = new()
    {
        {
            typeof(PlayerSerializer), new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "name", "player1Name" },
            }
        },
    };

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        if (_propertyNameConverter.ContainsKey(property.DeclaringType) &&
            _propertyNameConverter[property.DeclaringType].ContainsKey(property.PropertyName))
        {
            property.PropertyName = _propertyNameConverter[property.DeclaringType][property.PropertyName];
        }
        return property;
    }
}
```

I get the following output with "name" renamed to "player1Name" when running this code:

```
Console.Write(JToken.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = MyCustomContractResolver.Instance})));

{
  "players": [
    {
      "player1": {
        "player1Name": "Robert Bobbert"
      },
      "otherProp": "Tasty"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now the problem is that I would like "player1Name" to be directly under the root for the sake of this example (I would like this to be generic in the sense that in some cases I might want it under "players" or somewhere else). Meaning that my desired output would be:

```
{
  "player1Name": "Robert Bobbert",
  "players": {
    "otherProp": "Tasty"
  }
}
```

I tried accessing the parent properties and/or changing some properties on "property" in the ContractResolver to no avail.

For another example, I basically want what another user asked for here: [Newtonsoft Json How to write properties from inner class to parent class with out creating of inner class object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67127745/newtonsoft-json-how-to-write-properties-from-inner-class-to-parent-class-with-ou), but the only answer there mentions using dynamic and I'd rather not do it that way.

Comment: What happens if the `public IList<PlayersSerializer>? Players` contains more than one `PlayersSerializer`?  What do you want to see then?

Comment: A contract resolver resolves the contract for a specific type.  What you seem to want to do here is to restructure information between different types.  While it isn't impossible to do this with a contract resolver (see e.g. [Json.NET Custom ValueProvider to convert Objects into Guid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39818891/3744182)) Json.NET isn't going to make it easy.  Restructuring data between some subgraph of objects is really best handled by a custom `JsonConverter` and/or injection of a DTO.

Comment: See also [JSON.net ContractResolver vs. JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094764/3744182) where the answer by Brian Rogers suggests using a `JsonConverter` to *Translate between differing JSON and object structures*, and gives multiple examples.

Comment: @dbc To answer your first question, the specifics don't really matter as this is just a self-contained example and for some fields I might want to move the data to a parent while for other I might want to leave them as-is. The goal is mainly to translate one JSON object to another in a different format (that I don't have control over).

I wasn't aware of JsonConverter and from what I have read so far by consulting your links, it seems like it would be the correct solution to what I want to accomplish.

Thanks for your answers, I really appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can parse json and convert to a needed structure

```
    var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);

    Player player = new Player
    {
        Player1Name = (string)jsonParsed["players"][0]["player1"]["name"],
        Players = new Players
        {
            OtherProp = (string)jsonParsed["players"][0]["otherProp"]
        }

    };

[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class Player

{
    [JsonProperty("player1Name")]
    public string Player1Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("players")]
    public Players Players { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public partial class Players
{
    [JsonProperty("otherProp")]
    public string OtherProp { get; set; }
}
```

or you can use a dictionary if you have several properties, not just OtherProp

```
    var playerName = (string)jsonParsed["players"][0]["player1"]["name"];

    ((JObject)jsonParsed["players"][0]).Properties()
                    .Where(x => x.Name == "player1").First().Remove();

    Player player = new Player
    {
        Player1Name = playerName,
        Players = jsonParsed["players"][0].ToObject<Dictionary<string, object>>()
    };

[JsonObject(ItemNullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
public class Player

{
    [JsonProperty("player1Name")]
    public string Player1Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("players")]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Players { get; set; }
}
```